# return a value of a function embedded in another function

Tags: r

I would like to ask how can we get a value of a function which is embedded in another function, as in the following example:

```
message <- function() {
    inside.message <- function() {
        return("inside.message")
    }   
}

run.f <- function() {
    return.inside.mesage <- message()
    print(return.inside.mesage)
}           

run.f() # We do not get "inside.message"
```

Thank you in advance, all of you

Comment: Thank you a lot both BenBarnes and Joshua Ulrich. Really intuitive answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote it, the function `message` returns a function, which if evaluated will return "inside.message". So there are a couple ways to get R to print "inside.message".

First way:

In the `message` function, add the line `return(inside.message())` so that the function `inside.message` is evaluated and the result is returned, instead of returning the function itself:

```
message <- function() {
  inside.message <- function() {
    return("inside.message")
  }
  return(inside.message())
}

message()
# "inside.message"
```

Then evaluating `run.f()` will also print "inside.message".

The second way:

Leave `message` as you have it and change `run.f()` to the following

```
run.f <- function() {
  return.inside.mesage <- message()
  print(return.inside.mesage())
}
```

Above, you assign the function returned by `message()` to the object `return.inside.message` and then evaluate that function.

Comment: We have entered the twilight zone.

Comment: I bet we're long-lost twins, separated at birth.

Answer (score 2):

In your code message() returns a function. To call it, you need to add an extra pair of brackets:

```
> message()()
[1] "inside.message"
```

if you replace message() by message()() in your code it will do what you want.

Comment: Thank you @Apostolos :) I like R for that too, that we can add brakets behind brackets (works with square brackets too). This notation is so short and it works.

Answer (score 1):

As you've written it, `message` returns the function `inside.message` because you didn't explicitly return anything and it is the last expression evaluated inside of `message`.

You seem to want it to return the value from *evaluating* `inside.message`, which requires another line of code in `message`:

```
message <- function() {
    inside.message <- function() {
        return("inside.message")
    }
    inside.message()
}
```